# How to avoid Duplicate values for INSERT in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table named:

```
Delegates
```

This table has four fields:

```
ID(Auto increment, Primary)
MemberNo, FromYr, ToYr
```

I am inserting with this query:

```
INSERT INTO Delegates ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr]) values(@MemNo, @FromYr,@ToYr)
```

The values comes from user input. One member can be a Delegate for any year that's why I allow them to input as they want. But now problem is they can insert mistakenly one member for the same year more than 2 times. 
Please help me what can I do now here?

Comment: What is the natural unique key then? Not the IDENTITY value

Comment: no unique key is there actually.

Comment: @barsan: well, can't be done then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before inserting check if there is a record with the same values:

```
if not exists (select * from Delegates d where d.FromYr = @FromYr and d.MemNo = @MemNo)
    INSERT INTO Delegates ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr]) values(@MemNo, @FromYr,@ToYr)
```

Comment: This will fail under high load

Comment: Didn't know that, putting it inside of transaction would fix that?

Comment: @gzaxx: no it won't unless you use a performance killing lock strategy

Comment: I have been using this approach for years. However now i'm experiencing duplicate inserts several times a day. So I can confirm that this fails under high load.

Answer (score 20):

Use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
MERGE INTO Delegates D
USING (values(@MemNo, @FromYr,@ToYr)) X ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr])
ON (insert unique key join)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr]))
VALUES (X.[MemNo],X.[FromYr],X.[ToYr]);
```

Comment: I think you have an extra close parentheses on Insert line?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a unique index on that column, then inserting duplicates will cause an error. You can then error handle it if it needs to fail gracefully

Answer (score 2):

Try this, (I have not verified)

```
INSERT INTO Delegates ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr]) values(@MemNo, @FromYr,@ToYr)
where @MemNo not in 
(
    SELECT MemNo FROM words WHERE FromYr = @FromYr
)
```

Comment: I get an error when using the WHERE clause with INSERT INTO... VALUES. The consensus seems to be that you must use an INSERT SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

make a stored procedure that will first make a check on the whether the values are already contained in the DB. if they arent you will do your insert. If they simply ignore it

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid inserting duplicates with this simple, one line of code:

`INSERT INTO Delegates (MemNo, FromYr, ToYr) SELECT @MemNo, @FromYr, @ToYr WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Delegates d WHERE d.MemNo=@MemNo AND d.FromYr=@FromYr)`

If it's a high load environment where another command could insert the duplicate while this command is executing, you can use the `WITH(HOLDLOCK)` hint.