# what happens when same button clicked again before completion of execution of code under click event in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know  what happens when same button clicked  before completion of execution of code under click event in asp.net web application.Does the request goes in queue or it get disturbed by same event by other user.

Comment: It will run the event again. You should disable the button click so it can't register the click again until the process has run and then re-enable it (if need be) once complete.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, in web forms disabling button after first click that's unusual behaviour.

Comment: @andrey.shedko how so? It stops the user performing the action again before it has had chance to complete.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, I mean that if you're doing this intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it depends on the action you are going to perform. if you are inserting values into a database, it could cause duplicate entries but If you are making some complex operations on button click then multiple clicks can cancel the process also.

Comment: yes i am using insert statement but data will be different by different users.And also i am using two insert statements in it and using primary key(out parameter) from of first insert statement in another insert statement.So confused what to do .because if one user click submit button with his data and execution is in between two insert statements and another user clicks submit button with his data how can i handle situation.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand asp.net page lifecycle. When you're clicking button you;re not only fire some event but also send your web form to the server.
So if you fast enough to double click or your form is slow enough, you will send your form to the server twice. 
Result of this could be completely different depend  of the code executing at this moment. Normally nothing bad will happen between your first click and first time event fired, but as I told it depends of the code executing by this click.

Comment: i am not asking about double click by same user .Click by another user on same application and from  different machine.

Comment: You must clarify your question like "What's going to be if insert two records to database at the same time."

Comment: This question is more about SQL, altough you can check also in c# is the record exist, but it's simpler to do trigger somethinng like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442901/how-to-avoid-duplicate-values-for-insert-in-sql

Comment: dear @addrey.shedko  your not getting my question.