# Using "Trigger" to prevent the person from adding

Tags: sql

I'm preventing the user from adding the same surname in the list in the code array below. But my goal is to check all the lines using the 'trigger'. As a result: what do I need to do to check all the columns?
In summary: Check all columns. If the same value is entered, prevent it from being added.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_example
ON dbo.information
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @surname varchar(30)
select @surname = Person_Job FROM inserted
IF(@surname = 'Enderson')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The person with this record already exists in the list.'
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO personel.dbo.information(Person_id,Person_FirstName,Person_LastName,Person_Salary,Person_Job)
        SELECT Person_id,Person_FirstName,Person_LastName,Person_Salary,Person_Job FROM inserted
    END
GO
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u00T7.png)

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) I don't understand what you are trying to do.  What is a "code array"?  What are "all the columns"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Duplicate values for INSERT in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442901/how-to-avoid-duplicate-values-for-insert-in-sql)

Comment: How is the data being entered? Business rules should be handled at the business layer of an application, not at the data layer.

Comment: Think about unique indexes/constraints. Though I believe you may do something wrong here. Why shouldn't there be more than one person with the surname of Enderson (just think of a person having parents they usually share the surname with) in the real world? Or even the same given and surname... So why do you want to constrain that?

Comment: @WEI_DBA: Well, if it concerns the data integrity and not having duplicates of  some sort may well fall into this category, the database is exactly the right place to implement that.

Comment: mark it as unique!!!

Comment: For unique indexing of surname column please add see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Comment: 'anderson' only example. My goal is to prevent the same person from entering again.

Comment: @stickybit. Agreed to a point... I don't think a `Trigger` is an efficient way to handle what OP is looking for.

Comment: But I want to do this with trigger.

Comment: @WEI_DBA: And I agree in turn that a trigger seems to be the wrong tool for enforcing uniqueness. ;)

Comment: Using a trigger in this situation is equivalent to this I think https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mark the column as unique
 add up a constraint:

```
   unique
```