# How to Insert value into main field in Wix Corvid

Tags: velo

I have event table in Corvid Database, it has Event_Id column for every new event which is not asked from the user in the form.

I used the following code to get the number of rows and generate id from that which works good now:

```
    let count = 0;
  $w("#collection").onReady( () => {
     count = $w("#collection").getTotalCount(); // 23
       count++; 
  } );

$w('#btnSub').onClick( ()=>{
const newRequest = {
    eventid:('event_'+count),
    title: $w('#title').value
}
wixData.insert('event_instance', newRequest);
```

but this can lead to duplication of event id as I delete one of the row from collection

Can you please find a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to [this](https://support.wix.com/en/article/getting-started-with-corvid-by-wix)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dropdowns` in `#myElementID`

This similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442901/how-to-avoid-duplicate-values-for-insert-in-sql) in SQL.

`if not exists (select * from Delegates d where d.FromYr = @FromYr and d.MemNo = @MemNo)
    INSERT INTO Delegates ([MemNo],[FromYr],[ToYr]) values(@MemNo, @FromYr,@ToYr)`

Else refer [this](https://support.wix.com/en/article/getting-started-with-corvid-by-wix#step-3-add-elements-to-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Make sense get count before each insert

```
$w('#collection').onReady( () => {
  $w('#btnSub').onClick( () => {
    const count = $w('#collection').getTotalCount() + 1; // here

    wixData.insert('event_instance', {
      eventid: ('event_' + count),
      title: $w('#title').value
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: if I add 3 items, so it will give a count of 3 and if I delete the second element, then it will give me a count of 2 and my two events will be event 3 and event 3